# How to count the number of rows of this postgres JOIN GROUP BY (within a Rails scope)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Rails 4 scope set up to make it easy for me to find users who have ordered a certain number of times. My problem is that when I put a .count on the end of the scope, it does not return me a count. The underlying SQL it's generating seems wrong. How can I fix this?

The relevant schema is a simple User and Order model. My scope within the User model is:

```
scope :with_order_count_of, -> (count) {
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON users.id=orders.user_id').group('users.id').having("COUNT(orders.id)=#{count}")
}
```

When I invoke it like this:

```
User.with_order_count_of(0)
```

It returns me the proper users. The SQL it's generating is:

```
SELECT users.* FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS on users.id = orders.user_id GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(orders.id) = 0;
```

My problem is that I regularly want the count of these. However, this does not work. It returns me a hash of { user_ids => 0 }

```
User.with_order_count_of(0).count
```

The SQL it's using is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, users.id AS users_id FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS on users.id = orders.user_id GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(orders.id) = 0;
```

What's going on here? In Postgres, the COUNT is applying within the GROUP BY rather than COUNTing up the total number of rows. I was fiddling with raw SQL and I can get the correct result with SQL if I do a nested query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) (SELECT users.* FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS on users.id = orders.user_id GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(orders.id) = 0) q;
```

The problem is that rails is not doing this when I put .count on the end. I know I can do .length instead of .count and ruby will give me the right answer, but my tables are huge so I want the counting to happen at the SQL level.

How can I fix up my scope so that this gives me the proper users:

```
User.with_order_count_of(0)
```

**And** this gives me the count of users:

```
User.with_order_count_of(0).count
```

---

I've gotten a little closer to my answer. If I can figure out how to override the `.count` scope in rails, then I think I can do this:

```
scope :count, -> {
  existing_scope_sql = self.connection.unprepared_statement { self.reorder(nil).to_sql }
  if existing_scope_sql.downcase.include? 'group by'
    self.find_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) as count_all FROM (#{existing_scope_sql}) q").first.count_all
  else
    super
  end
}
```

Rails won't let me do this. I spent awhile googling and I cannot figure out a way. Can anyone help finish this solution or suggest another solution?

Comment: Rails doing the query with `.count` properly. But the raw sql you have shown, which you told is what you want needs a different treatment. :) `Comment.group(:post_id).count` will give you a Hash as a result which will be `{post_id_1: count_1, post_id_2: count_2}` format. Well, you want in your case the summation of `count_1 + count_2` always. Am I right ?

Comment: No, I don't want the summation of counts. I want the number of rows. My initial scope is basically giving me rows of user_id_1, order_count_1. This because I already have a count in the HAVING. That's what is confusing rails, when I do .count it's adding another count(*) to the query.

Comment: Never ever do a "#{count}" in a SQL string fragment, or you will end like a php programmer. SQL-Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can achieve what you want using Postgresql's [*window function*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) concept.

You have the below scope for now :

```
scope :with_order_count_of, -> (count) {
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON users.id=orders.user_id')
  .group('users.id')
  .having("COUNT(orders.id) = ?", count)
}

# window function is triggered using over()
scope :total_orders_count, ->() {
 with_order_count_of.
 select("users.id, sum(count(*)) over () as total_count")
}
```

Comment: Arup, that is two separate scopes. I'm simplifying my situation a bit, but I need to write a single scope that returns a list of users *and* accepts .count chained onto the end of it.

Comment: @KeithSchacht .. You can chain 2 scopes. Right now the scope `with_order_count_of` can be reused in another cases.